# Multiple close votes

Tags: discussion, bug

I saw this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216828/how-to-change-my-android-lock-screen-from-terminal) , then checked if there was old questions about the same topic. I saw a duplicate. When I wanted to post it (the duplicate) but another user already did. I upvoted his comment. Then saw the close button and voted.

What I noticed was that the close vote was at 1. By the time I upvoted the comment and voted to close the question, it was at 3; meaning that I possibly voted twice.
Is this a bug or maybe did another user vote to close it at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another user who voted to close 40 seconds before you.

Here's [the post timeline](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/216828/timeline) shown for mods. (Regular users won't be able to see the close voters until the question is closed)

> [image]

Comment: I am relieved. Thanks